# How to add and remove classes on button clicks

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular. I have a component with some HTML that outlines some basic information, such as a title and some sub information like date.

I have a couple of buttons that I would like to use to change the fonts live by adding a class. When I click any of the three buttons, a class can be applied to the parent div (I believe using CSS I can then change the children elements accordingly, opposed to adding classes to each element) such as `designOne`/`designTwo` whilst the other one is removed.

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="albumHeader"> Header One </h1>
  <span class="albumDate"> 12/12/2017 </span>
  <span class="albumCategory"> Jazz </span>
</div>


<button> Design One </button>
<button> Design Two </button>
<button> Design Three </button>
```

Comment: So what have you tried, and what precisely is the problem with it? Currently you don't appear to be handling click events or setting a class, so it's no surprise this doesn't work as you describe.

Comment: You will need to be more specific than *"assistance"*, SO isn't a tutorial service. Please review [ask] and the other material in the [help], then [edit] the question accordingly. I'd also recommend running through [the Angular tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial), which introduces a lot of what you will need to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very easy way to do that is to bind your parent class attribute to a Component property and to change this property by buttons clicks.

Template:

```
<div [class]="currentParentClass">
    <h1> class="albumHeader" Header One </h1>
</div>
<button (click)="switchClass('designOne')"> Design One </button>
<button (click)="switchClass('designTwo')"> Design One </button>
```

Component:

```
private currentParentClass = "designOne"

switchClass(selectedName: string) {
    this.currentParentClass = selectedName
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks @hiper2d for a decent response to help a newbie! Appreciate your time and knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

A ng-class on the parent div with the correct condition should do the work.
By clicking on a button, you will change a variable that is used in the condition by using a ng-click.

angularjs : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

angular : https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass